# Autolayout Contraints Changing When View Is Reloaded - Swift

Tags: swift, autolayout, tableview, nslayoutconstraint

recently in the search VC of my app I have been having a major problem with the contraints for weeks. I've redone them 4 times now with no improvement. My tableview cell is not complex -- an imageView located at the left and two labels on top of each other. Most cells size fine. The only thing is that(without pattern) two cells are randomly messed up(the labels and imageView move way out of place). You can see here:
[image]
[image]

Here is a picture of the constraints for the vc:

[image]

The strange thing is that this sometimes occurs when I toggle the scopeButtons up top. I looked in my code to see if I could fix this when the scopeButton reloads the tableview, but I could not find a problematic instance. My code is below:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Kingfisher

class SearchPostsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var idArray:[String] = []

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var candies = [Person]()
    var filteredCandies = [Person]()
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
            //initiate the search bar that appears up top when view is segued to
        }
        if let selectionIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectionIndexPath, animated: animated)

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Database.database().reference()
            .child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts")
            .queryOrderedByKey()//keys were out of order, so we have to use this to help
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot.childrenCount)
                for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    print(child.key)
                    self.idArray.append(child.key)
                }
                var reversedNames = [String]()
                for arrayIndex in 0..<self.idArray.count {
                    reversedNames.append(self.idArray[(self.idArray.count - 1) - arrayIndex])
                    //reverse names so we dont have to sort the cells by date
                }
                for x in reversedNames{
                    self.searchNames(id: x)//get names from the ids here, tada!!!
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })

        //self.tableView.reloadData()//without this, the results wouldnt show up right away
    searchController.searchBar.setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white], for: .normal)

        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Posts", "Users"]
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search posts or usernames"
        searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true

        if let splitViewController = splitViewController {
            let controllers = splitViewController.viewControllers
            detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 74
    }

//    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
//        candies.removeAll()
//    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DAY69:GRADUATION DAY", for: indexPath) as! SeachCell
        cell.cellImageVIew.frame.size.width = 48
        cell.cellImageVIew.frame.size.height = 48

        let personUser: Person
        if isFiltering() {
            personUser = filteredCandies[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            personUser = candies[indexPath.row]
        }
        //PERSON USER IS IMPORTANT!!!!! ^^^
        cell.nameLabel.text = personUser.name.removingPercentEncoding
        cell.messageLabel.text = personUser.category.removingPercentEncoding

        let name = personUser.name
        Database.database().reference().child("users/\(name)/profileImageURL").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let profURL = "\(snapshot.value!)"
            let profIRL = URL(string: profURL)
            //set up imageview
            cell.cellImageVIew.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.cellImageVIew.layer.masksToBounds = false
            cell.cellImageVIew.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            cell.cellImageVIew.layer.cornerRadius = cell.cellImageVIew.frame.height/2
            cell.cellImageVIew.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.cellImageVIew.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            cell.cellImageVIew.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            cell.cellImageVIew.kf.setImage(with: profIRL)

        })
        //TODO: make an extension of imageview to do all this for me. It's getting to be ridiculous
        return cell
    }

    func searchNames(id: String){
//        var message = String()
//        var name = String()
        Database.database().reference().child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts/\(id)/message").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
//             message = snapshot.value as! String

        Database.database().reference().child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts").child("\(id)/username").observe(.value, with: { (username) in
//            name = username.value as! String
            let user = Person(category: "\(snapshot.value!)", name: "\(username.value!)", id: id)
            self.candies.append(user)
            print( "\(snapshot.value!)", "\(username.value!)")
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
        })

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if isFiltering() {
            return filteredCandies.count
        }

        return candies.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 74.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
//    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
//        return 74
//    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DAY69:GRADUATION DAY", for: indexPath) as! SeachCell
        cell.cellImageVIew.frame.size.width = 48
        cell.cellImageVIew.frame.size.height = 48

        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles?[searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]

        if scope == "Users"{
            let username = candies[indexPath.row].name
            print(username)
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "userClicked", sender: username)

        }
        if scope == "Posts"{
            let post = candies[indexPath.row].category
            let user = candies[indexPath.row].name
            let id = candies[indexPath.row].id
            print(post)
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(id, forKey: "ID")
            let def2 = UserDefaults.standard
            def2.set(post, forKey: "Post")
            def2.set(user, forKey: "USER")
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "postCellTapped", sender: nil)
        }

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    //__________tbv methods above________________________________________________
    func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
        // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
        return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        filteredCandies = candies.filter({(candy : Person) -> Bool in
            let doesCategoryMatch = (scope == "Posts") || (scope == "Users")
            print(searchText)

            if searchBarIsEmpty() {
                return doesCategoryMatch
            }
            if scope == "Users"{
                return doesCategoryMatch && candy.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)!.lowercased())
            }
            else{
                return doesCategoryMatch && candy.category.lowercased().contains(searchText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)!.lowercased())
            }

        })
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let personalUser: Person
                if isFiltering() {
                    personalUser = filteredCandies[indexPath.row]
                } else {
                    personalUser = candies[indexPath.row]
                }

            }
        }
        if segue.identifier == "userClicked" {
            if let nextView = segue.destination as? UserProfileController {
                nextView.selectedUser = "\(sender!)"
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func isFiltering() -> Bool {
    let searchBarScopeIsFiltering = searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex != 0
    return searchController.isActive && (!searchBarIsEmpty() || searchBarScopeIsFiltering)
    }
}
extension SearchPostsController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    // MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
        filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
    }
}
extension SearchPostsController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    // MARK: - UISearchBar Delegate
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in trying to fix the constraints! Thanks!

Comment: First **super.viewWillAppear(animated)** called once Second you shouldn't add observers in cellForRowAt indexPath as it will create multiple duplicate observers to avoid this have a model to pass those **profileImageURL** for cellImageView.

Comment: Try calling `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` before returning cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.